# missing method in jar built by sbt

Tags: java, sbt

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering` is thrown when I trying to run a jar built by sbt. I decompiled that jar and found that it is missing that method.

However, on other node, everything is okay. Same project and same version of sbt(0.13.8), don't know where go wrong.

update:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.3.6"
  val sprayV = "1.3.2"
  val jacksonV = "2.4.1"
  val kamonVersion = "0.5.2"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.poi"                   %   "poi"                      %   "3.12"
  , "org.apache.poi"                   %   "poi-ooxml"                %   "3.12"
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-routing"            %   sprayV
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-can"                %   sprayV
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-client"             %   sprayV
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-http"               %   sprayV
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-testkit"            %   sprayV                    % "test"
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-json"               %   "1.3.1"
  , "io.spray"                         %%  "spray-caching"            %   "1.3.1"
  , "org.scalatest"                    %%  "scalatest"                %   "2.2.1"                   % "test"
  , "org.reactivemongo"                %%  "reactivemongo"            %   "0.11.1"
  , "com.github.nscala-time"           %%  "nscala-time"              %   "1.2.0"
  , "com.typesafe.akka"                %%  "akka-actor"               %   akkaV
  , "com.typesafe.akka"                %%  "akka-slf4j"               %   akkaV
  , "com.typesafe.akka"                %%  "akka-testkit"             %   akkaV                     % "test"
  , "org.specs2"                       %%  "specs2-core"              %   "2.4.15"                  % "test"
  , "com.gettyimages"                  %%  "spray-swagger"            %   "0.5.0"
  , "ch.qos.logback"                   %   "logback-classic"          %   "1.1.2"
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-core"             %   jacksonV
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-annotations"      %   jacksonV
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-databind"         %   jacksonV
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" %   "jackson-dataformat-yaml"  %   jacksonV
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype"   %   "jackson-datatype-joda"    %   jacksonV
  , ("com.sksamuel.elastic4s"         %% "elastic4s-core"             % "1.6.0")
  , "org.scala-lang.modules"           %%  "scala-async"              %   "0.9.3"
  , "org.apache.velocity"              %   "velocity"                 %   "1.7"
  , "com.github.mauricio"              %%  "mysql-async"              %   "0.2.15"
  , ("joda-time"                       %   "joda-time"                %   "2.7")
  , "mysql"                            %   "mysql-connector-java"     %   "5.1.34"
  , "org.apache.commons"               %   "commons-email"            %   "1.2"
  , "commons-lang"                     %   "commons-lang"             %   "2.6"
  , "commons-codec"                    %   "commons-codec"            %   "1.9"
  , "com.typesafe.akka"                %% "akka-contrib"              %   akkaV
  , "com.typesafe.akka"                %% "akka-testkit"              %   akkaV
  , "org.mongodb"                      % "mongo-java-driver"          %   "3.0.1"
  , "com.github.scullxbones"           %% "akka-persistence-mongo-rxmongo" % "0.4.0"
  , "org.reflections"                  %   "reflections"              %   "0.9.10"
  ,"org.apache.kafka"                  %   "kafka_2.11"               %   "0.8.2.0" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization="org.slf4j"))
  , "com.oracle"                       %   "ojdbc14"                  %   "10.2.0.4.0"
  ,"org.elasticsearch"                 % "elasticsearch"              %   "1.6.0"
  , "io.kamon"                         % "kamon-core_2.11"            % kamonVersion
  , "io.kamon"                         % "kamon-log-reporter_2.11"    % kamonVersion
  , "io.kamon"                        %% "kamon-system-metrics"       % kamonVersion
  , "org.aspectj"                      % "aspectjweaver"              % "1.8.5"
  , "io.kamon"                        %% "kamon-akka"                 % kamonVersion
  , "io.kamon"                        %% "kamon-spray"                % kamonVersion
  , "io.kamon"                         % "kamon-annotation_2.11"      % kamonVersion
  ,"com.unboundid"                     % "unboundid-ldapsdk"          %   "3.0.0"
  )
}
```

Suppose the working node is A and the dysfunctional one is B. I delete jackson-core-2.1.1 jar on both nodes, after sbt compile, node A didn't download that jar but node B did. It's really strange.

Comment: What is different between the two nodes?

Comment: Did you decompile the JAR on the other node as well to verify it is in there?

Comment: I did verify it and it's in there.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Same sbt, same java and same project I don't know what else could effect the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has finally beed solved by forcing sbt to use jackson-2.4.1.

```
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-core"             %   jacksonV force()
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-annotations"      %   jacksonV force()
  , "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"       %   "jackson-databind"         %   jacksonV force()
```

I printed the dependency tree of the whole project and find no transitive dependency on jackson 2.1.1, but somehow sbt package it into fat-jar.